# Booting SD card from UEFI

Tags: windows-8, boot, bios, uefi, sd-card

I've come across the problem.

I'm trying to boot a bootable SD Card using UEFI.

However, this doesn't work, as there is no "SD Card" boot option AFAIK.

I have tried putting all the USB-related options before the hard disk in the boot order.

**I know the SD Card is bootable because it can boot through changing UEFI to Legacy, and booting either from "USB Key" or "USB CD/DVD"**

However, I can't use Legacy in order to install the OS on the SD card, as it would mess with the MBR and render my UEFI Windows 8 broken or corrupted (or so I am told).

I've also tried disabling Secure Boot Mode and using a SD-to-USB adapter (which I will try using again, there may have been a driver problem).

If you need any more info, I'll try and give it to you.

Thanks!

Comment: It is possible to boot in Legacy mode **and then revert to UEFI protected mode**, if the UEFI boot records have not been damaged or deleted.

Comment: It is possible to install and run Windows 8.1 in Legacy/MBR mode. But why don't you create an UEFI flash drive in lieu of the SD card. Use Rufus ==> http://rufus.akeo.ie/